# Как зайти в BIOS UEFI через Linux Mint?

Tags: linux, bios, uefi

Как зайти в BIOS UEFI через терминал Linux Mint
(не предлагать варианты кнопок delete и.т.д просто не вариант в  моём случае)

Comment: `systemctl reboot --firmware-setup` вроде работает

Comment: @andreymal Не! Не работает пишет переменная EFI не поддерживается в этой системе (Linux mint 19 Tara)

Comment: Значит не судьба

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface